# How can I guarantee a hat drop?

Tags: team-fortress-2

How can I get a hat? I've been playing for ages, and haven't got a darn tootin' thing.

Comment: God I need to know this. I've been playing for 450hrs+ and have only had 1 hat drop :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While a real drop cannot be guaranteed, you can craft yourself a hat.

3 refined metals will craft into a random hat.  4 refined metals and a class token will craft a class-specific hat.

It takes two drops to create a scrap metal, three scrap metal to create a reclaimed metal, and three metal to make a refined metal. A class token is created by crafting three weapons of that class.

So for a random hat, it takes at minimum 54 items.  For a class-specific hat it takes at minimum 75.

For more crafting detail, visit the [official wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting).

Comment: hope they implement trading soon!

Comment: @marco: Me too. I've run out of room in my backpack :(

Comment: Trading has been added in the time since these comments were posted.

Comment: Note that Unusual hats do not drop nor can they be crafted.  They can only be gotten from opening Mann Co. Crates and trading.